# When would you use entiende vs entiendes?

Tags: verbos

If I wanted to ask someone if they understand, what should I use:

- ¿Entiende?
- ¿Entiendes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you ask in English and may have some trouble following Diego's answer I provide a reply in English.

Spanish has different forms of you for formal and informal use. The first form you quote is the formal second person (usted) and is identical with the third person (él/ella). The second form is the informal one (tú).

The tricky bit, especially for a foreigner, is knowing when to use which. In my experience in Spain when talking to work colleagues of the same status *tú* is almost universal. You also use it when speaking to younger people, animals, and on the internet. If you obviously sound like a foreigner nobody is likely to be very offended if you use the wrong form but if in doubt use the formal one and wait for them to correct you. The issue is discussed on this site in questions tagged [ustedeo](/questions/tagged/ustedeo).

Dieago's answer also tells you about the plural forms and various other helpful bits of information but this answer should give you a Spanish learner's experience.

Answer (score 2):

**(Tu) *Entiendes*       (Usted) Entiende**

---

*El verbo entender [en-ten-der] tiene una conjugación verbal irregular y es pronominal, es decir que se puede conjugar de manera reflexiva como entenderme, entenderte, entenderse, entendernos, entenderos y entenderse*.

Principalmente utilizamos la segunda persona del presente "*(tu) entiendes*" como forma cercana de hablar con alguien, esta manera más abierta de interactuar la llamamos "tuteo", "tutear" ó tutearse" con alguien, así podemos tratar o tratamos de tú, a un amigo, a un compañero, etc.  Igualmente usamos la tercera persona del presente " *(el, ella, usted) entiende*" para dirigirnos hacia otro con cierto respeto ó inicial desconocimiento, así empleamos el "usted" con un profesor, un juez, un policía, una persona mayor que nosotros ó simplemente alguien que no conocemos, según los casos.

Por último, ¡entiende! se puede emplear de forma imperativa "entiende (tu)".

Si te refieres a los plurales plural, también en presente, "¿(vosotros) entendéis?" ó "¿(ellos, ellas, ustedes) entienden?". En Imperativo el plural seria " (Vosotros) Entended" y " (Ellas, ellos, ustedes) Entiendan".

Espero te haya servido. Un saludo.

Diego M.

Comment: Buena respuesta, aunque si alguien no sabe la diferencia entre tú y usted/él/ella, no creo que la *entienda*. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ciertamente, la forma "¿Entiende?" se usa para el modo formal, mientras "¿Entiendes?" se utiliza en el registro menos formal (o coloquial).

En cualquier caso, es habitual utilizarlo en la forma "¿Me entiende?" y "¿Me entiendes?" respectivamente.